# Determining semi-open subsets of Cantor Space

Tags: general-topology

The Cantor space is the product of $\mathbb{N}$ many copies of $\{0,1\}$ which is $\mathcal{C}=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Definition: A subset $A$ of a space $X$ is said to be semi-open if $A\subset cl(int(A))$ where cl and int denotes closure and interior operator. It is clear that every open set is semi open. Denote the product topology and $\mathcal{C}$ by $\tau$ and class of all semi open sets of $\mathcal{C}$ is $SO(\mathcal{C})$.

I was confused about determining the class of semi open subsets of $\mathcal{C}$. Since the interior of product does not always imply the product of interiors, It became challenging to determine. Is there any semi open subset of $\mathcal{C}$ which is not open? Or $\tau=SC(\mathcal{C})$? I could not go now, any hint or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is well-known (and easy to see) that a space is globally disconnected (which is stronger than extremal disconnectness), if and only if all semi-open sets are open. Moreover, a first countable, extremally disconnected space is discrete. Hence, in a non-discrete metric space there always exist semi-open subsets, which are not open.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I think it still will be very hard $SS(\mathcal{C})$ @Ulli

Comment: No, I think it is easy to find semi-open, non-open sets. But, sorry, I don't have time now for a concrete answer.

Comment: Thank you sir. I actually can wait for discussing it when you are available @Ulli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in my above comment, a metric, non-discrete space $X$ always contains a semi-open set, which is not open:

Since $X$ is metric, not discrete, there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of pairwise distinct elements converging to $x \in X$, such that $x_n \neq x$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then an easy proof shows that 
(*) there exist paiwise disjoint, open sets $U_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_n \in U_n$ for all $n$. 
Let
$U := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{2n}$ and
$V := \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_{2n+1}$.
Then $U, V$ are open and disjoint, $x \in \overline{U} \cap \overline{V}$. Hence $\overline{U}$ is semi-open, but not open.  (If $\overline{U}$ was open, then $\overline{U} \cap V \neq \emptyset$, hence $U \cap V \neq \emptyset$.)

Here is a concrete realization in $\mathcal{C}$, which avoids (*):
Let $U_n := \{(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}: x_1 = \dots = x_n = 0, x_{n+1} = 1\}$. Then $U_n$ is open and $(U_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ pairwise disjoint.
Let $U, V$ be defined as above. Then $(0, 0, \dots) \in \overline{U} \cap \overline{V}$. Hence $\overline{U}$ is semi-open, but not open.

Comment: thank you so much for the illuminating answer. Can we say that $\mathcal{C}$ is semi-compact which every semi-open cover has a finite subcover? or any equivalence ? @Ulli

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is open (in any space $X$) and $U \subseteq A \subseteq cl(U)$ then $A$ is semi-open. So we just want to find a $U$ in $\mathcal C$ with an $A$ that is not open. $\mathcal C$ has the topology generated by the lexiographical ordering. If (a,b) is a no-empty open interval in that ordering then $\overline{(a,b)} \subseteq [a,b]$ but it can be open. But if $a$ and $b$ are specified to be sequences which are not eventually constant, then $\overline{(a,b)} = [a,b]$ and $[a,b],[a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ are all semi-open but not open.

Comment: Thank you very much